# Baking Turkey Meatloaf with/out glass cover

Tags: baking, equipment, meatloaf, casserole

I am baking 2.5lbs of turkey meatloaf with a mixture of sauteed onions and red bell-peppers. There are no set recipes for cooking a meatloaf of this size so I basically doubled some of the ingredients.

The regular recipe says to Bake at 350 for 50 mins for 1.5lbs. I'm using a ceramic casserole dish and was wondering if the glass cover would help cook the inside of this dense loaf more than with it uncovered? Another thing I heard is to place a cookie sheet under the casserole dish for radiant heat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting the lid on will tend to steam your meatloaf on top, rather than baking it, as the moisture that evaporates from it will have no where to go.   This will inhibit getting those nice crispy brown bits.

If I were to double a meatloaf, I would not simply put it in a larger casserole.   Instead, I would make two... erm... loaves.  This would:

- Ensure that they cook at approximately the same and expected rate, as predicted by the recipe
- Provide more surface area for the delicious brown bits.

Comment: Absolutely correct, I wouldn't say anything different.

Comment: I should have known this would happen. So I baked without covering for an hour and other than it being extremely moist (maybe from too much sauce), it came out at 155 perfectly. Thanks!